# Can sentence-endings in speech-to-text processing in Android be attached to?

Tags: android, text-processing, text-parsing, speech-to-text, sentence

Presuming that the speech-to-text engine/capability that can be used in Android "knows" (guesses) when a sentence is complete and adds a period, is there a callback/event handler that can be attached to this occurrence so that the text being generated can be handled a sentence, or a chunk, at a time?

Comment: you could split your text on '.'

Comment: That's presuming my first presumption is a valid one (that the speech-to-text engine susses out where the period belongs and adds it). At any rate, I want to do this in "real time" - so I need some event handler/callback to observe when a "." appears in the generated text.